# Missing total amount in receipt after civicrm upgrade 4.5 to 4.6

Tags: upgrade, contributions, tokens, receipts

I have upgrade civicrm 4.5 to 4.6. After that token `{$formValues.total_amount|crmMoney:$currency}` is not printing the total amount in emails.
The template used is one of the `System workflow messages` called `Memberships - Receipt (on-line)`.

Any ideas on why this could be happening ?

Thanks in advance!